# how to download a link in links using axel/curl?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, axel, lynx

shortly, how can I make lynx/links use axel/curl for downloading files that i want to store in my hard-disk??

Longley:
I'm a server-manager and always used my ubuntu system and putty so i could copy/paste url with mouse and  +  :D
but now I don't have any graphical env. to use; so I need a way to download files that I found to download using links/lynx via axel/curl.

Note that I have axel, curl, links and lynx installed on my both server and client machines and also I use ssh to access the text terminal. Also I use bash for my default shell and have (t)csh, dash, and sh on both machines.

Also note that a way to export the exact link url to a text file could work because I still can tell axel/curl to download them with help of bash and python scripting.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

How about elinks instead of links?

If you have in .elinks/elinks.conf:

```
set document.uri_passing.Save-URL = "echo %c >> ~/urls"
bind "main" "S" = "link-external-command"
```

Then when you have a URL highlighted in elinks, you can press `S` to write its URL to ~/urls ...

Comment: ah! good idea but ...  
for security reasons I can not install any new pkg and I don't want to do so! cuz I could compile it from source but for lots of reasons I don't want to do so!  
but TnX as you told me how to dump link url to a text file ;) and even you could find a way that work with lynx ... ( as s.b. told me that it could dump it to a txt-file too but also told he don't remember regarding to the nowadays GUIs :( ) :))